# Can you ever stop the raiders?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Does upgrading the vault door do anything other than simply slow down (and not by much in my experience) the raiders trying to get into your vault?

I mean I appreciate the delay so the armored and gunned up people can get to the entry way to stop them, but it just seems like that is all it is good for, a bit of time before they will always get in... with their swords.. some how getting through 5-6 feet of steel... Whatever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I couldn't stop them too with the vault door. It's just like the fire. It will appear some time and will appear ever. :-D

Only way is to get your hardest boys with the strongest armor and the biggest guns into your vault door to kick their asses as fast as they can.

By the way, upgrading the vault door decrease the chance that a raid will occur.

Comment: Biggest guns seems to be what really makes a difference. On my first play, I only had a small pistol when my first raid occured. In my second one, I had a supercharged laser gun (YES!) and 2 raiders died at the door before moving to the next room. First time I had better armors.

Comment: Yes this makes a big difference. I have the biggest guns in the upper rooms, so even if they pass the vault they will die in the next room. But remember, even the lower rooms need guns. Don't sell the worse guns if you still have people which are fighting with their fist.

Comment: Actually, I have been selling the guns with an attack value of 1.  That's the same attack value as fists, so I don't see the need to keep them in the inventory.

Comment: Yes. I'm currently at the state of selling everything below 3. Even 2-3 weapons. You will gather later on really good weapons and even a bunch of them. Currently one guy is in the outlands for 23 hours and has a bunch of weapons in his hold (10+). You will get many of them later on.

Comment: They run into my kitchen, where they are met by sniper rifles, flame throwers and mini nukes.. 2 of them die before they even reach the center.. Its just annoying cause I can't move people around until its done :D

Comment: Yeah, don't waste your time putting people in the door room. Just keep the people in the top room equipped at all times.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the vault door to advanced and beyond won't stop raiders from breaking in, but it will give you more time to get your best armed and armored dwellers to the vault to keep them at bay, which can be important if those dwellers are assigned to rooms very deep in the mountain.